# Google Maps API v3 Second Map Resize and Center

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i forgot the embed maps on wordpress and moved to the google maps api v3.
So, i'm using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

and this function:

```
function initialize() {

//replace 0's on next line with latitude and longitude numbers from earlier on in tutorial.
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.654372, -7.914174);
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(30.654372, -6.914174);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var myOptions1 = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

//here's where we call the marker.
//getElementById must be the same as the id you gave for the container of the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), myOptions1);
 //google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
 //map1.setCenter(myLatlng1);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title:"ADD TITLE OF YOUR MARKER HERE"
  });

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '<\/div>'+
    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">ADD TITLE HERE<\/h2>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p style="font-size:1em">ADD DESCRIPTION HERE<\/p>'+
    '<\/div>'+
    '<\/div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});      

  // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
  marker.setMap(map);  
  }

  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
```

as you can see, there are two maps declared. Im my website, i'm using horizontal tabs to alternate between showing maps.

The problem is one i found in other topics here, but the solutions gave there doesn't seem to work. as you can see in the lines i commented:

```
//google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
```

//map1.setCenter(myLatlng1);

this code is not working to center the second map. The map does not fit on the div correctly, and the center icon is on the left the corner, the usual problem.

I guess you already know what the problems are, however if you need pictures i will provide them without a problem.

How the tabs code looks on wordpress:

```
    [wptabs type="accordion" mode="horizontal"]

[wptabtitle] Portugal[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]

<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid;"></div>
[/wptabcontent]

[wptabtitle] Brasil[/wptabtitle] [wptabcontent]

<div id="map_canvas1" style="width: 100%; height: 300px; border: 1px solid;"></div>

[/wptabcontent]

[/wptabs]
```

Comment: As you're using tabs to view maps, I think you need call this events when you change tab that correspond to each map because the map does "not exist" when placed in a hidden element.

Comment: I guess you're right since if i put the second map together with the first one everything is fine.
But how can i do that? Can you give me a help please?

Comment: I do not know wordpress well. You can show how these tabs are being generated? So I try to help with something.

Comment: It's through a plugin. I updated the code of the main post.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that this plugin uses [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), then you can do something like this:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.panel.id == "tab-map-2") {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
        map1.setCenter(myLatlng1);
    }
});
```

Where **#tabs** is outside div ID and **tab-map-2** is your tab panel ID for second map.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but this jquery part i can put inside the javascript file where i have the code for generating maps?
or should i put it in a different file?

Comment: You can put anywhere after initialize the map and tabs.

Comment: Hmm, it's not working, i put the code after the initialize function ends. But i don't know if i'm doing things right about #tabs and tab-maps-2.
i have to create a div with id="tabs" where i put the code of the tabs?
About the "tab-maps-2", i guess in this plugin the id of each tab is given by the text between the tags [wptabtitle][/wptabtitle] so i guess i have to name it "tabs-map-2".

Comment: You can open HTML code on your browser to check these IDs. By [this demo](http://kav.in/projects/blog/wp-ui-tabs-accordion-sliders-demo/), the plugin generate **wp-tabs-1** for outside div. The tab ID is the text of each tab.

Comment: I do as you suggest. So, judging from the code, i guess the outside div is named "wp-accordion-1" since it's a style they allow on this plugin. But about the second tab of this "accordion" i couldn't see any id in the source code.
You can check yourself here if you want:
explicacoes-brunosoutinho.com/contactos/

Comment: Sorry, you're using accordion, not tabs. So, use **accordionchange** event instead **tabsshow**.

Comment: So i put it like this; $('#wp-accordion-1').bind('accordionchange', function(event, ui) {

But Paulo i dont' know what to put it after "ui.panel.id" since i dont' see any id on the code :/

Comment: h3 has the ID you're looking for, it's tab-map-2.