# Google Map is not rendering properly for same div if tried for second request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Master/Child type page. In master page there a link which open detail page. On detail page I am displaying Map. Detail page is opened in fancy box with Ajax call. On first iteration of detail page click, I am appending google script to page. I am not appending google script from next detail click as Script already added to DOM.  On first iteration of detail page click, Map is loading properly but after that Map is not rendering properly. Map rendered in only half part of div.

Code snippet as below for

```
var instanceTime = 0
function loadgoogleapiInfoPopup() {

    mapCanvasId = "map_canvas_gdi";
    if (instanceTime == 0)
    {
        instanceTime = 1;
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.id = 'GoogleAPIMapInfoPop';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=infopopup.Init';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    else {

        $("#map_canvas_gdi").html('');        
        infopopup.Init();
        google.maps.event.trigger(infopopup.Map, 'resize');

    }
}

infopopup.Init = function () {    
    function initialize() {
        var center = new google.maps.LatLng(53.961687, -1.746825);

        var options =
        {
            zoom: 6,
            center: center,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        infopopup.Map = null;
        infopopup.Map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapCanvasId), options);


    }

    initialize();
    infopopup.ClearMarkers();
    infopopup.FillMarkers();
}
```

Comment: I have had this kind of problems with Google Maps when appending in hidden divs, and making them visible later. Can't remember exactly how I solved it, but it might be something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12621124/734151 Have a try at the trigger resize, and setCenter methods every time you show the map ?

Comment: If that still fails, also try setZoom(14) each time you show the map, looking at my old code I think that helped solve it.

Comment: Both(setCenter(), setZoom(7)) is already implemented in my FillMarkers() methods.. Still not working..

Comment: Thanks ..Problem is solved , I have applied google.maps.event.trigger(garagemapinfopopup.Map, 'resize'); in parent page, after child loaded in div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ..Problem is solved , I have applied google.maps.event.trigger(garagemapinfopopup.Map, 'resize'); in parent page, after child loaded in div.